# correct Scala 3 syntax for providing a given from a higher order function argument

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3

In Scala 2 I could have written something like this:

```scala
// a function that needs an implicit context
def funcWithCtx(arg1: String)(implicit ctx: Context) = ???

myObj.doSomething { implicit ctx => // mark argument as the implicit context
  funcWithCtx("arg1")
}
```

This syntax works in Scala 3, but I thought `implicit` was being deprecated and `given` \ `using` was being used instead? I've tried to replace `implicit` with `given` but the compiler doesn't like that.

```scala
myObj.doSomething { given x => // this fails!
  ...
}
```

Is this one place where the `implicit` keyword is still required?

Comment: *shrug* The new syntaxes are just more confusing and messy.

Comment: I added one more option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, correct is

```
myObj.doSomething { ctx =>
  given Context = ctx
  ...
}
```

or

```
myObj.doSomething { case ctx@given Context =>
  ...
}
```

[Allow `given` bindings in patterns](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/7194)

Comment: yeah, that's what I ended up doing. I don't like using `implicit` when the new syntax is `given` and it's a shame we end up adding a new line with extra boilerplate.

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/discussions/12007